# MobileFirst 8.0 : Multiple Adapters for one Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am new to MobileFirst

Requirement is -

> There is already a developed (in IBM Mobilefirst) mobile application (andriod native)
>   and now I have to create another application (with security feature)
>   which is going to be a part of (as plugin) main application.

So, Is Adapter required for 2nd application development, can we have only mobile application without adapter? 
If yes, then can we have multiple adapters for a single application?

Thanks you,
Mrunal

Comment: Yes, you can have any number of adapters for a single application.

Answer (score 2):

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0, You can have any number of Security Check and Resource Adapters for a single application and Also you can use same adapters in multiple apps too.